# Как привязать метод bind к load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Подгружаю контент на страницу с другой страницы. Если информация считывается некорректно, то нужно при помощи метода bind() вывести сообщение об этом. Как это сделать?

```
$("#result").load("university.html");
```

Comment: В лоаде есть колбек, пробовали его использовать?

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня есть конкретное задание, где нужно, цитирую: " при некорректном считывании файлы при помощи метода bind() вывести мигающее предупреждение об этом. "

Comment: А кто такие условия поставил?

Comment: Преподаватель. Поэтому вопрос и возник. Ибо, если сказано в задании, значит это можно сделать. С колбеком то все понятно, но задание....

Comment: делайте через коллбек, в случае претензий преподавателя шлите его в интернет обучаться

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то у jQuery.ajax уже есть все нужные методы для обработки запросов.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "university.html",
    success: function (result) {
        $("result").html(result);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        // тут можно вывести сообщение об ошибке
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Решила проблему следующим образом:

```
.done(function (json) {

                $("#result").load("university.html");

                document.getElementById('name3').innerHTML = 'Номер группы ' + json.students[0]
                + '<br>' + 'Дата поступления' + json.students[1]
                + '<br>' + 'Дата окончания' + json.students[2]
                + '<br>' + 'Староста группы' + json.steward
                + '<br>' + 'Число студентов в групе всего' + json.number;
            })
            .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
                var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
                $("body").bind("mousemove", function () {
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        if (flag == 0) $("#error").append('error! ');
                        flag = 1;
                    });
                });
            });
```